# How do I distribute data files across Windows, Mac, and Linux

Tags: windows-xp, mac

I have some data files that I want to make available to users of Windows, Mac, and Linux. The files are pdf and mp3. I can use Windows Installer or a self-extracting zip file for Windows, but I need to be able to create files that will work on Mac and Linux. I do not have a Mac and I don't run Linux, so I need to be able to do all of this from Windows (I'm running XP). Is this feasible?

Thanks,

Jolyon Hallows

Comment: What do you mean by distribute? Centrally deploy to all machines? no user input?

Comment: It's been a couple days... If you still need information, edit your question or add a comment so I can improve my answer, or others can answer

Answer (score 0):

If you are distributing single files, you can just give out the .PDF or the .MP3. If you need to combine files, try the .ZIP method, which is readable natively from all versions of Windows from XP on, and OSX and most Linux distributions

1. Select the files to compress in Windows
2. Right-click the files, select `Send To`->`Compressed Folder`.
3. Give the archive a name, then distribute the .zip it creates